# Export a project to Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode

Is possible to import already created project (using Xcode 3.2.4 and iOS SDK 4.1) to Xcode 3.2.5 and iOS SDK 4.2

Comment: What have you already created this project in?

Comment: Sorry, what do you want to do again?

Answer (score 3):

If you have an excode project you can simply copy all the files in the project's directory and move them wherever you want or zip them, and then simply open the project file from the new location!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply copy the whole project folder and then later simply double click the .xcodeproject file and you have imported it.

hope it helps if you have some other questions just ask it

[wblade](http://wblade.com)